# use docker-client api to start container in Java project

Tags: java, docker

I am now using docker client api https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java in my Java project:

```
CreateContainerResponse container = 
    dockerClient
        .createContainerCmd("ubuntu:java7")
        .withCmd("true")
        .exec();
dockerClient
    .startContainerCmd(container.getId())
    .exec();
```

When I start a new container using docker client api,the container is created,but i also finished.I use command "sudo docker ps" to list the running container now, what I created is not shown.I want to create the running container in my Java project using the docker client api,how should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Your container is probably not running. `docker ps -a` will show you all containers, including the stopped ones.

Comment: You say you have some code. Edit your question and include it.

Comment: Hello,thanks you reply.When I use java docker api to create and start the container,I can see what I created just now using "sudo docker ps -a".

Comment: **CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("ubuntu:java7")
    .withCmd("true")
    .exec();
  dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();**

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whats your usecase here. I think you are starting `container` in attached mode. As soon as you are done, the container exits. And you want that container to persist.

Use

```
.withTty(true)
```

while creating the container to detach.